# filterable property in schema

Tags: apex, soql, fields, standard-objects, schema

how to get fields which are queryable(can be used in query) or filterable(property from schema) from an object like account without using soql queries.
Any suggestions?
how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this done via apex, then use [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm?search_text=describe) & [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm?search_text=DescribeFieldResult) classes. These classes have method like isQueryable(), isFilterable(), isCreateable() and many more. Sample code snippets are already provided in the apex developer guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) & [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm#apex_describe_object_all_fields).

You can also use SOAP api. Check out [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) & [DescribeGlobalResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describeglobal_describeglobalresult.htm).

---

***Note that fields in Salesforce objects do not have a queryable attribute. This attribute is available at object level only and all the fields returned by describe object are queryable. That being said, you may run into issues using fields in a query's WHERE clause and that could be because of various reasons like lack of indexing. This usage of fields in WHERE clause is indicated by the field's filterable attribute.***

---

If you simply want to view this in an UI tool, you can login to [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) to get this information. Go to `info` > `Standard & Custom objects` > Select *object* under `Choose an object to describe` > Expand `Attributes` to view object level attributes or `Fields` to view the field attributes. Screenshot below for ref.

[image]

---

You may want to explore another popular tool [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en) available in chrome web store. Post installation, this tool is visible as utility icon on your browser page and quite easy to use.