# How to change the filterable property in a schema

Tags: soql, schema

I was working on an error in one of my queries and found [filterable property in schema](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325312/filterable-property-in-schema), and determined that filterable was set to false (using workbench as the aforementioned question answers).

How do I change the filterable property in a schema?

Note to the mods: The filterable question is a 'how do I check if this is a problem' question, and this is a 'how do I fix this' question. If this has an answer already and this is a duplicate please also put a link to the question this is a duplicate of in the question I'm linking too as a potential next steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change this (aside from maybe changing the field type on custom fields, which may be enough to toggle between filterable and unfilterable).

If a given field doesn't have the "filterable" property, then you simply cannot use it in the `WHERE` clause of a SOQL query.

In the case of "long text area" fields, you could instead use SOSL (e.g. `FIND 'John Doe' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact`) but you still can't filter on such fields.

In general, whatever operations (filtering, grouping, aggregating, etc...) can't be done with a query are things that you would need to write Apex to achieve.